# Creating a conference on Asterisk using ARI with Node.js

Tags: node.js, asterisk, asterisk-ari

I was given a task to create a conference in Asterisk using ARI with Node.js. The objective is create a conference room and send email invitations so people can click and enter de conference room. I also need a admin web interface to show who's talking, mute and some other things.
I don't have any experience in Asterisk. So I need some start point. Innitally I have to create a Channel and then add some SIP to it.

So taking this page as a base: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Channels+REST+API

I have a configured test server and a sip number (852001). So I opened up Insomnia and create a POST request like this:

```
http://<serverip>:8088/ari/channels/400?endpoint=852001&extension=400
```

But allocation failed. So I thought that before I continue with this I have to make some concepts clear:

1. What do I need to create a conference room ? It's just create a channel or I have to create a bridge first ? What should be the right values in endpoint, extension or app fields ?
2. Is ARI URLs the best approach or it's better to use node.js's ari-client module ? I'm using urls because I couldn't get any working example on creating a conference with ari-client.

Any code examples on how I could do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Read Orelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony" as starting point.

ps but do it via ARI only  seams like impossible even for expert. Anyway you need some dialplan.